# finding moment generating function

Tags: probability

I am having a bit of trouble finding the moment generation function for 
$f(x)=(\frac{1}{2})^{x+1}$ for $x=0,1,2,3,\ldots$

I know that $M(x)=\sum e^{tx}(\frac{1}{2})^{x+1}$ which I have rearranged to make $\frac{1}{2} \sum (\frac{1}{2}e^t)^x$ but I am not sure how to simplify this further.

Answer (score 2):

If $t<\ln 2$ then this is a geometric series. Recall that for $|a|<1$:
$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty a^x=\frac{1}{1-a}$$
So if $a=\frac{e^t}{2}$, and $t<\ln 2$...

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the moment generating function is defined as

$$E\left[e^{tX}\right]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}e^{ti}P(X=i)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}e^{ti}\frac1{2^{i+1}}=\frac 12+\frac12\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac {e^t}2\right)^i.$$

This is a geometrical series with $q=\frac {e^t}2.$ This series is convergent if $0\le q<1$: $t<\ln(2).$ The sum of the series is then

$$E\left[e^{tX}\right]=\frac12\left[1+\frac{e^t}{2-e^t}\right]=\frac{1}{2-e^t}.$$

Comment: The smallest value of $X$ is $0$.

Comment: @NCh: right. I'll edit.